# How to add symbols from System Frameworks (e.g. UIKit) when symbolicating a crash log?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I have a crash log from my iPad app and the corresponding dSYM file, so I can use the `symbolicatecrash` script to add the symbols from my code.  However, I'd also like to add the symbols from the System frameworks (such as UIKit, CoreFoundation, etc.).

Is there a way to add those symbols also?

I've noticed that the Xcode Organizer will add System framework symbols when it automatically symbolicates crash logs it gets from the device (even for apps that I got from the AppStore), so I assume that info exists somewhere.

**Edit:**

A few more details:

- The crash occurred on somebody ele's iOS device.
- They were running a Release build that was built on another machine (i.e. not my machine).
- I have the binary and dSYM file of the build they were running (on my machine, where Spotlight can see them).
- The crash log was downloaded to their computer (different than mine or the build machine) using iTunes.
- I tried dragging the crash log to the Xcode Organizer on both my machine and the build machine, but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried to drag the crash log into organizer?

Comment: I did try dragging to the Xcode Organizer (both on my machine, and the machine it was built on), but it didn't help.  I added a few more details to the question describing the situation.

Comment: I got the same problem. It seems that Xcode copy the system debug symbols from the iOS device that you have connected and "use for development". If you don't have the device + iOS version combo connected to your machine, you won't have the system debug symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You must drag both the .app and the .app.DSYM files matching the build used to produce the crash log into the PROJETS & SOURCES section of the Organizer window. Then, you must drag the crash logs into the IOS DEVELOPMENT/Device Logs section of that same window, and they will be properly symbolicated for you, with symbols for every frame of every thread.